# Broadcast receiver doesn't work after registering in onStartJob

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, firebase-job-dispatcher, jobservice

I use `FirebaseJobDispatcher` and `JobService` to do some work on the background. Mainly I want to register to a screen on/off receiver. When the job is called for the first time the receiver is registered as it supposed.
However, immediately after `onStartJob()`, `onDestroy()` is called and according to the logs, the receiver is null. If I try to trigger the screen to turn on/off I don't see any logs from the receiver. What am I doing wrong here?

In `onStratJob()` I have the following code:

```
public boolean onStartJob(@NonNull JobParameters job) {

    Log.i(JobFormActivity.TAG, "onStartJob() called");

    if (screenBroadcast == null){
      Log.e(JobFormActivity.TAG, "onStartJob() --> receiver is null, registering receiver");
      IntentFilter screenStateFilter = new IntentFilter();
      screenStateFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
      screenStateFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
      registerReceiver(screenBroadcast, screenStateFilter);
    }
 return false; 
  }
```

In `onStopJob()` I have the following code:

```
@Override
  public boolean onStopJob(@NonNull JobParameters job) {
    Log.e(JobFormActivity.TAG, "onStopJob() called");
    if(screenBroadcast != null) {
      Log.e(JobFormActivity.TAG, "onStopJob() --> receiver is not null, unregistering receiver");
      unregisterReceiver(screenBroadcast);
    }
    return false;
  }
```

In `onDestroy()` I have the following code:

```
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.e(JobFormActivity.TAG, "onDestory()");
    if(screenBroadcast != null)
        Log.e(JobFormActivity.TAG, "onDestroy() --> receiver is not null");
    else
      Log.e(JobFormActivity.TAG, "onDestory() --> receiver is null");
  }
```

Comment: Are you not seeing this log `onStartJob() --> receiver is null, registering receiver` after `onStartJob` is called? If yes, can you share the complete `FirebaseJobDispatcher` or `JobService` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that I forgot to initialize `screenBroadcast`in `onStartJob()` after checking if it's `null`. Also I was returning `false` in `onStartJob()` instead of `true`.

From [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService):

> Returning false from this method means your job is already finished.
>   The system's wakelock for the job will be released, and
>   onStopJob(android.app.job.JobParameters) will not be invoked.

And:

> Return true from this method if your job needs to continue running. If
>   you do this, the job remains active until you call
>   jobFinished(android.app.job.JobParameters, boolean) to tell the system
>   that it has completed its work, or until the job's required
>   constraints are no longer satisfied.

In my case, since I needed the broadcast receivers to be alive, I needed to return true so that onDestroy wouldn't be called and the receivers wouldn't unregister.